# Not working Currency formatter in angular ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Below code I used for the currency
[image]
Here the decimal formatter applied correctly.
Case1: when user types 123 or 12345.45 , then its formatting
Case2: when user types any other alphabets or special characters except dot(.) and numbers. Then will error as **"Invalid Format"** and also in column will display **0.00** as default value

In my case the value which is displaying is formatting correctly. But when I pass the row data to backend, then it is not taking the default value.

For example:- In column basePrice, if user types 123/45 , then in display I changed to 0.00 like below.

[image]

But when I pass the value to backend, it is passing like 123/45 itself

[image]

I want to apply formatter in storage value as well

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing your data to the back end?

And you should show your ag grid configuration

Aggrid formatter only formats what is displayed, it is not changing data behind (https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-formatters/).

According to the official documentation, you're supposed to use a `valueParser` to clean edited data: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-parsers/